# My text based game script is not working

Tags: batch-file, text-based

I am making a text based rpg and the script is not working. It has something to do with the stamina. I also have a quest that is dependent on you having a certain amount of gold and that script is not working as well. I will include pictures.

```
:harvest
cls
echo Press 1) to harvest
set /p input17=enter:
if %input17%==1 set   /a wheat= %wheat% + 5
if %input17%==1 set   /a carrots= %carrots% +4
if %input17%==1 set /a stamina= %stamina% - 25 (this line)
if %stamina% < 0 goto nostamina  (this line)
echo.
echo You get some wheat and some carrots.
echo.
echo check your inventory for accurate numbers.
echo. 
echo Press 1) to go back.
pause >nul
goto insidehouse






    :insidehouse
cls

echo You are now inside of your house.
echo.
echo Press 1) to harvest.
echo Press 2) to sell all crops.
echo Press 3) to go into your inventory.
echo Press 4) to sleep eight hours.
echo Press 5) to check for quests.
set /p input16=enter:
if %input16% EQU 1 goto harvest 
if %input16% EQU 2 goto market
if %input16% EQU 3 goto Inventory1
if %input16% EQU 4 goto sleep
if %input16% EQU 5 (and) if %gold% LSS 0 goto shopping (this line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided much code to work with so, I can only guess at a solution.

My best guess is that you are atempting to update a variable from inside a for loop. If this is the case you need to add this line to the top of your batch file: `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`. You will also need to access the affected variables like this `!var!` instead of this `%var%`.

`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` causes expansion of variables to delayed in your batch file. What this will mean in the context of your program is that variables can be updated from within a for loop.